# How to add a channel layer for a 3D image for 3D CNN

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am working on a medical dataset of 3d images the shape`image.shape` gives me (512,512,241) I assume it is height , width, depth but when I run 3D cnn i get this error `Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 1, 241, 512, 512] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead`. what should be done? I am using pytorch.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your network expects each slice of the 3d volume to have three channels (RGB). You can simply convert grayscale (single channel) data to "fake" RGB by duplicating the single channel you have:

```py
x_gray = ...  # your tensor of shape batch-1-241-512-512
x_fake_rgb = x_gray.expand(-1, 3, -1, -1, -1)
```

See [`expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.Tensor.expand.html#torch.Tensor.expand) for more details.

Comment: RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1700\3406775539.py in <module>
      2 
      3 print(transforms.ToTensor()(image).size())
----> 4 transforms.ToTensor()(image).expand(-1,3,-1,-1)

RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (3) must match the existing size (241) at non-singleton dimension 1.  Target sizes: [-1, 3, -1, -1].  Tensor sizes: [241, 512, 512]

Comment: Your idea was really good but I get this following error as above. can you please let me know how to solve this?

Comment: @Sohail you got this error because your `x_gray` is of shape 241-512-512 and NOT 1-1-241-512-512. Try: `x_fake_rgb = x_gray[None, None, ...].expand(-1, 3, -1, -1, -1)`